# Prevent users to see some views in landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've had to allow landscape orientation in all my views because one of them needs to handle landscape orientation and my app is a tabbar based iphone app. Now some views are obviously showing ugly when device is in landscape mode. I'm thinking of subclassing UIView and use the subclass to show a "warning" screen when user is not in a portrait mode in some views. Any idea on what could be of best practices about it ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation method in the UIViewController class. iOS calls it when an end user rotates phone. You may override it to display and hide a warning message.

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (! UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait (toInterfaceOrientation))
        [self displayWarningMessage];
    else
        [self hideWarningMessage];
}
```

Comment: Yes I know but I was asking if it's not against Apple guidelines